# How to access the related objects using select_related

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models as stated below -

**orders**

```
class Orders(BaseModel):

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Properties, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    ....
    ....
```

**properties**

```
class Properties(BaseModel):

    property_long_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    property_trading_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False)
    ....
    ....
```

**property owners**

```
class PropertyOwners(BaseModel):

    property = models.ForeignKey(Properties, related_name='property_owners', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
    ....
    ....
```

I am trying to query on `Orders` and want to put a lock on the rows it will return. I also want to lock the related row of `Properties` model. Furthermore, those properties will have one or many owners which is stored in model `PropertyOwners`. I want to lock those rows of `ProprertyOwners` which are related to the property of that order.

So far I have tried to do it like this, but it did not work and returned me an error -

Queryset

```
Orders.objects.select_related('property__property_owners').select_for_update().exclude(created_by=created_by).values('id', 'property', 'units', 'created_by', 'sell_price_per_unit', 'order_status').filter(property=order_obj.property, order_type__name=SELL, order_status__in=[PARTIALLY_COMPLETED[1], OPEN[1]], sell_price_per_unit__lte=order_price).order_by('sell_price_per_unit')
```

error -

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'property_owners'. Choices are: property_type, created_by, approved_by, property_manager
```

All the order returned by the queryset will belong to just one property. A property may have one or more many owners.

Comment: I don't think `select_related` would work for one to many relations. Even if it did you should have used `property_owners_set`. I have not tested this but try `.prefetch_related('property__property_owners_set')` instead.

Comment: @Selcuk, I tried this but doesn't work.